# Trouble setting up a Dropbox service in a headless Ubuntu server 12

Tags: dropbox, ubuntu-server

I'm using a headless Ubuntu Server 12 vm on Amazon ec2. I'm trying to set up Dropbox by following these [instructions](http://norwied.wordpress.com/2012/04/11/install-dropbox-on-a-headless-ubuntu-10-04-lts-server/). Everything was going fine until I got to this line:

```
ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-02-1D-34:~$ sudo service dropbox {start|stop|reload|force-reload|restart|status}
stop: missing job name
Try `stop --help' for more information.
reload: missing job name
Try `reload --help' for more information.
restart: missing job name
Try `restart --help' for more information.
/etc/init.d/dropbox: 2: /etc/init.d/dropbox: pbox: not found
No command 'status}' found, did you mean:
 Command 'status' from package 'upstart' (main)
status}: command not found
force-reload: command not found
ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-02-1D-34:~$ sudo service dropbox status
/etc/init.d/dropbox: 2: /etc/init.d/dropbox: pbox: not found
dropboxd for USER ubuntu: running (pid 641)
```

The `service dropbox {start ...}` command continued to give this error message after I rebooted. From the tutorial, it looks like I should be getting something like:

```
user@bluepill-server:/etc/init.d$ sudo service dropbox status
[sudo] password for user:
dropboxd for USER user: running (pid 2215)
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a command:

```
sudo service dropbox {start|stop|reload|force-reload|restart|status}
```

It is just showing you the usage for the service commmand.  To start dropbox, use only the start parameter:

```
 sudo service dropbox start
```

When ever you see a list seperated by pipe `|` enclosed in curly brackets `{}` it means that these are the parameters you can use in conjunction with the command.  `start` starts the service, `stop` stops it, `restart`, `reload` and `force-reload` all stop and start the service in this case.  `status` shows the running status.